# Issue getting delegate/protocol to work correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I am trying to create a way to pass data from Controller A (CDCFaderController) to Controller B (CDCSendsViewController) this is because although Controller A owns a view, I need to send some of that views data to Controller B as it has some additional functionality I want to access.

My logic was to setup the delegate in Controller A and receive it in Controller B for use.

Currently I have this as a test to get it working:

Controller A .h

```
@protocol CDCSendsControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)test:(NSString*)str;
@end

@interface CDCFaderController : UIViewController
<UIScrollViewDelegate, CDCControlDelegate, CDCFadersSideBarDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <CDCSendsControllerDelegate> delegate; // delegate synthesis
```

Controller A .m

```
-(void)delegateTest {
    [self.delegate test:@"Hello world!"];
}
```

And in the receiving Controller B:

Controller B .h

```
@interface CDCSendsViewController : UIViewController
<CDCControlDelegate, CDCSendsControllerDelegate>
```

Controller B .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"VDL CALLED");
    CDCFaderController * faderController = [[CDCFaderController alloc] init];
    faderController.delegate = self;
}

-(void) test:(NSString*)str{
    NSLog(@"%@", str);
}
```

The idea i thought was that when i loaded Controller B it would pull through the print from Controller A and display the information?

In practice controller B wont be instantiated by the view as Controller A is the owner of the view. So I was wondering how to get B to call and pull data from A correctly to get this working? B is more of a background controller adding support functionality to A by using some of its passed data.

Hope this helps I can provide any further detail

Comment: from where you'r trigering the delegate?

Comment: that may be the issue im not sure how to trigger it? i assumed it triggered on view did load of controller B? where you instantiate controller A and set its delegate to self

Comment: From where are you calling delegateTest?

Comment: If your  delegate does not triggered properly then delegate is not called in VC. First check your delegate is called or not from where you trigger the delegate. Second check delegate object in VC if it is nil or not.

Comment: thats what i said in the comment above yours, how would you call it if controller B isnt being triggered by a view? like A is

Comment: @dahiya_boy the delegate isnt null so that part is ok, but how would i trigger the controller B delegate funcs when a view isnt linked to it?

Comment: @jcad `[faderController delegateTest];` After self call this line. It automatically calls your delegate as a sample.

Comment: Ok i got the code to run, but to get it to run i had to load controller B's view, is there no way i can run the code on controller B when i load Controller A's view?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the above code. Actually your CDCFaderController is locally initialised in viewDidLoad method. ARC will release that controller object after viewDidLoad is executed as it is no longer used anywhere which will make the delegate nil as well.

Kindly make a property of CDCFaderController and initialise it. After that it should work fine.